# Add AngularJS directives as Attributes to dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The below code works fine, when I try to append a directive as element through the `$compile` method

```
restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        $reader.$().$call = function(bookDefaults) {
                var PageFrames = angular.element(document.getElementById(frameSelector)).children();
                _.each(PageFrames, function(frame) {
                    var iframeParent = angular.element(frame);
                    iframeParent.append($compile("<iframe-binder></iframe-binder>")(scope));
                });
        };
    }
```

But the following doesn't fire up [***I'm trying to add directive as attribute to a dynamically created element***]:

```
restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(elem.parent());
        $reader.$().$call = function(bookDefaults) {                
                var PageFrames = angular.element(document.getElementById(frameSelector)).children();
                _.each(PageFrames, function(frame) {
                    var iframe = angular.element(frame).find('iframe');
                    $compile(iframe.attr("iframe-binder", ""))(scope);
                });
        };
    }
```

In the second code the attribute seems to be added when I check the DOM tree, but the directive ***iframe-binder*** does not run.

**Iframe-Binder Directive**:

```
.directive("iframeBinder", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(elem);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Is this a right approach or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `$compile` expects an element.

Comment: @zeroflagL thanks a ton !!! just had to do `iframe.attr("iframe-binder", "")[0]` and it works like a charm.